# How to update insert new record with updated value from staging table in Azure Data Explorer

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-data-explorer, kql

I have requirement, where data is indigested from the Azure IoT hub. Sample incoming data

```
{
"message":{
  "deviceId": "abc-123",
  "timestamp": "2022-05-08T00:00:00+00:00",
  "kWh": 234.2
    }
}
```

I have same column mapping in the Azure Data Explorer Table, **kWh** is always comes as incremental value not delta between two timestamps. Now I need to have another table which can have difference between last inserted **kWh** value and the current **kWh**.

It would be great help, if anyone have a suggestion or solution here.

I'm able to calculate the difference on the fly using the prev(). But I need to update the table while inserting the data into table.

Comment: **(1)** Delta **is** incremental value. Your intention is not clear. **(2)** The only way that seems feasible is to run a recurrent batch process.

Comment: Have you considered an approach of calculating the difference on the IoT device itself before transferring the telemetry data to Azure Data Explorer? It would reduce the overhead of all the calculations that should be made on the fly during the data ingestion process.

Comment: I don't have a control over the device firmware. Anyhow it's good suggestion 

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to perform data manipulation on the fly and inject Azure IoT data to Azure Data explorer through JSON Mapping. However, I found a couple of approaches you can take to get the calculations you need. Both the approaches involve creation of secondary table to store the calculated data.

**Approach 1**

This is the closest approach I found which has on-fly data manipulation. For this to work you would need to create a function that calculates the difference of Kwh field for the latest entry. Once you have the function created, you can then bind it to the secondary(target) table using policy update and make it trigger for every new entry on your source table.

Refer the following resource, [Ingest JSON records](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingest-json-formats?tabs=kusto-query-language#ingest-json-records-containing-arrays), which explains with an example of how to create a function and bind it to the target table. Here is a snapshot of the function the resource provides.
[image]

Note that you would have to create your own custom function that calculates the difference in kwh.

**Approach 2**

If you do not need a real time data manipulation need and your business have the leniency of a 1-minute delay, you can create a query something similar to below which calculates the temperature difference from source table (jsondata in my scenario) and writes it to target table (jsondiffdata)

```
.set-or-append jsondiffdata <| jsondata | serialize 
| extend temperature = temperature - prev(temperature,1), humidity, timesent
```

Refer the following resource to get more information on how to [Ingest from query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-ingestion/ingest-from-query). You can use [Microsoft Power Automate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/flow#example-7---create-custom-html-table) to schedule this query trigger for every minute.

Please be cautious if you decide to go the second approach as it is uses serialization process which might prevent query parallelism in many scenarios. Please review this resource on [Windows functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/windowsfunctions) and identify a suitable query approach that is better optimized for your business needs.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using [Azure Stream Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-get-started-with-azure-stream-analytics-to-process-data-from-iot-devices) to process the data coming from the Azure IoT Hub before it is ingested into Azure Data Explorer?

[image]

You could create a **[Stream Analytics job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-live-data-visualization-in-power-bi#create-configure-and-run-a-stream-analytics-job)** that reads data from the IoT Hub, calculates the difference between the current and previous kWh values, and then outputs the result to a new Azure Data Explorer table. The output table would have the same schema as the input table, but with an additional column for the calculated difference.

**Use the New Table method:**
Create a new table in Azure Data Explorer with the following columns:
deviceId, timestamp, kWh, and kWhDifference.

When inserting data into the table, use the following query to calculate the difference between the last inserted kWh value and the current kWh:

```
let lastKWh = prev(kWh);
let kWhDifference = kWh - lastKWh;
insert into <new_table_name> (deviceId, timestamp, kWh, kWhDifference) values ("abc-123", "2022-05-08T00:00:00+00:00", 234.2, kWhDifference);
```

This query will calculate the difference between the last inserted kWh value and the current kWh and insert the result into the new table.

You can also use the following query to update the new table with the difference between the last inserted kWh value and the current kWh:

```
update <new_table_name> set kWhDifference = kWh - prev(kWh) where deviceId = "abc-123" and timestamp = "2022-05-08T00:00:00+00:00";
```

This query will update the kWhDifference column in the new table with the difference between the last inserted kWh value and the current kWh.

**Alternatively**, you could also use Azure Functions to perform the calculation and update the table in real-time whenever new data is inserted into the input table as suggested in the previous response.